# Parent Account not required

Tags: account

I understand that Parent Account field is required on Page Layout of Business Account record-type. However, we do not have business requirement of having Parent Account.

Is there any workaround you might have come up with for similar Use Case?

Comment: Note : I know there is always Visualforce Page solution for such requirements. But I would not like to go for such customization for this feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the page layout to make the field read only and then move it to an inconspicuous place on the page. See this good PDF on how to get started with modifying page layouts: https://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_pagelayouts_cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: Well, that option is not applicable for Parent Account field as Out of Box, Salesforce makes it required for Business Account Page Layout (marked with blue filled circle saying "Always on Layout"). An idea too is raised on same issue : https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bq1v

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread your question. I thought you said it was a required field on the page. You just don't want to display the field at all.

Comment: that is correct.

Comment: I just updated the answer: how about making the field read only?

Comment: agreed. 1) I just made field read-only 2) Gave a Help-Text saying that "This field is not to be used" (can update it to what business wants later) 3) Put it in a "Redundant Fields" section (can rename it to whatever business wants) at the bottom of the Account detail part of the page layout 4) Collapsed that section. Thanks for the direction.